# img src not working to showing Images Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

i am  beginner of Laravel 8. i creating simple project. but when i view the project images are not shown.
View Page

**Index.php**

```
 <div>     
   <img src="{{asset('/images/chocolate-ice.jpg')}}"  id="Chocolate" class="photo" width="100" height="100" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
   <b>Chocolate</b>
 </div>
```

[image]

**Folder structure**

Comment: what `img src="` is generated in you html please check that and put in your question

Comment: img src not working to showing Images Laravel 8

Comment: i set the folder structure also correct why

Comment: check from google chrome and anything  in `<img` tag put that in question https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open#:~:text=the%20DevTools%20UI.-,Open%20the%20Elements%20panel%20to%20inspect%20the%20DOM%20or%20CSS,the%20element%20and%20select%20Inspect.&text=Or%20press%20Command%20%2B%20Option%20%2B%20C,%2C%20Linux%2C%20Chrome%20OS).

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7B%7Basset('/images/chocolate-ice.jpg')%7D%7D   i just go to inspect on console and test the url look like that

Comment: your php function in not rendering  how your calling this model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Blade your template/view must end in `.blade.php`. That is how the view system knows what view engine to use. When it is just `.php` it does **not** use the Blade compiler to parse the template.